# How do I use AWS S3 without Amazon Cognito?

Tags: ios, node.js, swift, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I am using a Node.js REST API to authenticate my users. Once they are authenticated I allow them to post photos with text. My plan is to store the text and the URL to the photo in the database. That way when they go to the feed of posts, my app will query the database to get the text and URL's and then use all of the URL's to get the images from S3 directly. Is this the correct way to do it and if so how come I can not do so without using cognito. I am trying to cut costs and it seems like cognito would be useless since I already add authentication with my API.

Here is the code I have thus far.

```
    let S3BucketName = "*******"

    // configure authentication with Cognito
    let CognitoPoolID = "*************"
    let Region = AWSRegionType.USEast1
    let credentialsProvider = AWSCognitoCredentialsProvider(regionType:Region,
                                                            identityPoolId:CognitoPoolID)
    let configuration = AWSServiceConfiguration(region:Region, credentialsProvider:credentialsProvider)
    AWSServiceManager.defaultServiceManager().defaultServiceConfiguration = configuration

    let ext = "png"
    let imageURL = NSBundle.mainBundle().URLForResource("iimage", withExtension: ext)!

    let uploadRequest = AWSS3TransferManagerUploadRequest()
    uploadRequest.body = imageURL
    uploadRequest.key = NSProcessInfo.processInfo().globallyUniqueString + "." + ext
    uploadRequest.bucket = S3BucketName
    uploadRequest.contentType = "image/" + ext

    let transferManager = AWSS3TransferManager.defaultS3TransferManager()
    transferManager.upload(uploadRequest).continueWithBlock { (task) -> AnyObject! in
        if let error = task.error {
            print("Upload failed (\(error))")
        }
        if let exception = task.exception {
            print("Upload failed (\(exception))")
        }
        if task.result != nil {
            let s3URL = NSURL(string: "http://s3.amazonaws.com/\(S3BucketName)/\(uploadRequest.key!)")!
            print("Uploaded to:\n\(s3URL)")
        }
        else {
            print("Unexpected empty result.")
        }
        return nil
    }
```

Answer (score 9):

For without cognito use this in

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
    AWSStaticCredentialsProvider *credentialsProvider = [[AWSStaticCredentialsProvider alloc] initWithAccessKey:AWS_ACCESS_KEY secretKey:AWS_SECRET_KEY];

    AWSServiceConfiguration *configuration = [[AWSServiceConfiguration alloc] initWithRegion:AWSRegionAPSoutheast1
                                                                     credentialsProvider:credentialsProvider];

    AWSServiceManager.defaultServiceManager.defaultServiceConfiguration = configuration;
}
```

and for uploading image use

```
AWSS3TransferManager *transferManager = [AWSS3TransferManager defaultS3TransferManager];

AWSS3TransferManagerUploadRequest *uploadRequest = [AWSS3TransferManagerUploadRequest new];
uploadRequest.bucket = AWS_S3_BUCKET_NAME;
uploadRequest.key = @"cards/image.png";
uploadRequest.contentType = @"image/png";
uploadRequest.body = imageURL;

[[transferManager upload:uploadRequest] continueWithExecutor:[AWSExecutor mainThreadExecutor]
                                                   withBlock:^id(AWSTask *task) {
                                                       if (task.error) {
                                                           if ([task.error.domain isEqualToString:AWSS3TransferManagerErrorDomain]) {
                                                               switch (task.error.code)
                                                               {
                                                                   case AWSS3TransferManagerErrorCancelled:
                                                                   case AWSS3TransferManagerErrorPaused:
                                                                       break;

                                                                   default:
                                                                       NSLog(@"Error: %@", task.error);
                                                                       break;
                                                               }
                                                           }
                                                           else
                                                           {
                                                               // Unknown error.
                                                               NSLog(@"Error: %@", task.error);
                                                           }
                                                       }

                                                       if (task.result)
                                                       {
                                                           AWSS3TransferManagerUploadOutput *uploadOutput = task.result;
                                                            NSLog(@"success: %@", uploadOutput);
                                                       }
                                                       return nil;
                                                   }];
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. This works. The Upload is successful but I am not able to see images inside the Bucket. Am i missing something?

Answer (score 0):

One easy way to accomplish this is to have your server generate a presigned URL and send that URL back to the mobile app. An example if your server is written in Java is http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/ShareObjectPreSignedURLJavaSDK.html . All of the AWS SDKs support generating a presigned URL if your server is in another language.

This way your AWS credentials need only be on your server, and after you have authenticated your users you can give them back the URL for access (which will expire after a set period of time).

Keep in mind if you do end up needing to authenticate with AWS down the road that the Cognito Identity APIs are free.

Comment: Where do you see these APIs are free? I'm looking at https://aws.amazon.com/cognito/pricing/

Answer (score -2):

AWS S3 allows unauthenticated users.  You still have to set up an account, obtain a bucket, and set policies (permissions).

Go to this link and review the services policies.  You'll want to look at IAM and S3.

I am adding an edit. Hopefully this helps:

Use the following:

```
    AWSS3TransferManagerUploadRequest *uploadRequest = [AWSS3TransferManagerUploadRequest new];
uploadRequest.bucket = @"bucket name";  
uploadRequest.key =  fileName;
uploadRequest.body = url;  //This is a temporaryURL for the file stored at your client.  

AWSS3TransferManager *transferManager = [AWSS3TransferManager defaultS3TransferManager];

// Execute the request 
[[transferManager upload:uploadRequest] continueWithExecutor:[AWSExecutor mainThreadExecutor] withBlock:^id(AWSTask *task)
{ 
    if (task.error)
    {
        // do something
    }
    else
    {
        // do something
    }

}];
```

The S3 bucket has local policies so that you can set it up to allow unauthenticated users; you are charged for the storage, of course, if the user abuses this access.

Comment: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/awsconsolehelpdocs/latest/gsg/obtaining-permissions-for-resource-groups.html

Comment: User is asking to review the code if it is correct for the required operation. Above answer is not the answer to the above question.

Comment: OK.  I anticipated that the user was reluctant to sign in to AWS to establish the policy for the bucket.  The code is fine.  It looks as if it were directly produced by an AWS code generator.  The user should log in to AWS to establish an unauthenticated identity.

Comment: The user, ConnorB, expresses interest in reducing costs.  There are no additional authentication costs, since the CognitoPoolId and Region are incidental to the app (not the user) and cost nothing.  The AWSServceManager part is required only once in the app, nominally it can be put in the appDelegate.

Comment: @digitalR so by creating an identity pool, it will cost me nothing? I can not use s3 with my code unless I use Cognito to create an identity pool

Comment: This answer really confused me. Should I keep my current code (which works) and make an identity pool and region or should I add policies to my s3 bucket and cut out cognito all together? I don't mind using an identity pool if it does not cost anything more @digitalR

Comment: @ConnorB,  Since cost is your driver, I recommend that you keep your code intact.  The pool id will cost you nothing.  While the user can be unauthenticated (anonymous), the pool id allows AWS to consider the app as a generalized entity that can be assigned privileges. Also, instead of assigning permissions directly at the S3 bucket, you will need to attach a policy to the unauthenticated user (defined when you create your Cognito pool id) that defines the entity's capabilities with your S3 bucket.